# Как удалить ключ реестра Windows 10 с помощью Windows.h в C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, реестр

Мне нужно удалить ключ реестра Windows 10, и я написал на C такой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void main() {
    LSTATUS A = RegDeleteKeyA(
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
        (LPCSTR)"Test"
    );
    if (A == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("1");
    }
    else {
        printf("0");
    }
}
```

Он также выводит 0 или 1 в конце, чтобы было понятно, прошло ли удаление успешно. В реестре я создал в ветке HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ключ (раздел) Test, его и хочу удалить. Но ничего не выходит. Удаление значения ключа проходит нормально, а вот сам ключ удалить не получается. Я пробовал функцию RegDeleteKeyW, которая вроде как отличается от аналога с A в конце только типом данных второго аргумента, это тоже не помогло. Что делать? Скрин из редактора реестра:
[image: реестр]

Использую компилятор Visual Studio.

Comment: Программа 32-битная или 64?  Regedit 32 или 64 битный? (На Win64 есть два независимых реестра.)

Comment: Два замечания... `RegDeleteKeyEx` не пробовали? И — "*Удаленный ключ не удаляется, пока не будет закрыт последний дескриптор.*" — что получается, если перегрузить компьютер?

Comment: Мне как-то нужно было в пакетном файле удалить несколько параметров реестра. Я использовал REGEDIT с параметрами. Или вариант system("regedit ключи..."). Но в Windows 100% есть функции, которые это делают. Поищите их :)

Comment: Система у меня 64-битная, RegDeleteKeyEx я пробовал, не помогло. "Удаленный ключ не удаляется, пока не будет закрыт последний дескриптор" - тут это стандартный дескриптор, уже открытый, - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, закрывать его по сути не надо. Перезагрузка ничем не помогла. Точное значение A я не знаю как вывести, поскольку я не знаю спецификатор типа данных LSTATUS, может быть, кто-то здесь знает, как вывести A?

Comment: Как-то даже не вспомнил сразу... Вы же ее с правами администратора запускаете? Или нет? А выводить... Можно сразу с сообщением о проблеме: `char msg[256]; FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,0,A,0,msg,256,0); printf("%d %s\n",A,msg);`

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, запустил с правами администратора и получилось